# Filter rows by timestamp in Large Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp, xts, large-data

I have a large data frame with 32 million rows in R. I want to filter it using custom timestamp duration. But for this large dataset, R Studio is crashing everytime I am trying to convert it to XTS object to filter data.

```
XTSDATA <- xts(dataset[, -1], dataset[, 1])
Data_filt <- XTSDATA["T09:30:00/T15:30:00"]
Data_df <- data.frame(date=index(Data_filt), coredata(Data_filt))
```

Can anyone please suggest. Below is the sample of data I have.

```
    times           value   size    stockName
2/1/2016 9:15:01    91.8    500     TV IS Equity
2/1/2016 9:15:02    92.4    1420    TV IS Equity
2/1/2016 9:15:04    92.2    5000    TV IS Equity
2/1/2016 9:15:05    91.9    6524    TV IS Equity
2/1/2016 9:15:06    91.9    11524   TV IS Equity
2/1/2016 9:15:06    92.05   6824    TV IS Equity
2/1/2016 9:15:08    92      1824    TV IS Equity
2/1/2016 9:15:08    92.05   4972    TV IS Equity
2/1/2016 9:15:13    92.2    6704    TV IS Equity
2/1/2016 9:15:14    92      1       TV IS Equity
```

Thanks.

Addl. Info: The data is in RData file which is directly downloaded from Bloomberg using API package. So for this kind of large data set I am not using excel. Also I have planned to divide data for each security and each trading day in nested for loops and then filter timestamp interval from there. But that will be a lengthy process indeed. So I was hoping if anyone can suggest any process for entire dataset at same instance.

Comment: How big (GB) is your data? How big (GB) is your RAM? (Just to make sure...)

Comment: In windows the RData file size is showing approx 117MB (around 32 million rows) in size. But when loading the file in RStudio, it is showing approx. 710MB in size. My system has 4GB RAM.

Comment: Can I clarify that RStudio crashes in the first of your lines (the conversion from `dataset` to `XTSDATA`)? I.e. it never gets to lines 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes. In first line it crashes.

Comment: If you can load the entire "long data object" into R (as a data.table/frame) without an issue, then an obvious way to reduce the size of your data objects in memory is to subset by stockName so you are dealing with individual securities.  It make sense to operate on  your data as separate symbol/stock name objects in most cases.  Also, stockName is a character (categorical) variable type, so your whole xts object you create will be converted to character type if you keep that column on creation of the xts object.  Do you realise this?

Comment: Given that the data takes up 710 MB while RAM totaling 4 GB suggests the size is not the issue (unless I misunderstand something about `xts`). If working on subsets of data doesn't help, it may be useful to try other ways of achieving the same result (there are packages like `lubridate` and `dplyr` which do good job with dates and categorical data).

Comment: @FXQuantTrader - 1. yes, I am aware of character conversation in using xts. 2. I also tried individual securities wise, but somehow it is showing exceeding memory error and after couple of securities successful run the code is failing. I assume, as I have already total data loaded in environment, that might have to do something with memory. I am looking into that issue.

Comment: @jakub - xts as well as simple subset of dataframe both are not working. But thanks for the ideas with lubridate and dplyr. I will try to use them.

Comment: @jakub - Is it really good to use dplyr for this kind of large dataset? I think I have seen one or two posts for dplyr issue when dataset is larger than 2M rows. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Zico I mean, it all depends. Given your response to FXQuant, I would say the memory might be the issue after all. R is in habit of making copies of things as part of many operations (see [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)), and they all need to fit in the memory. Out of your 4 GB, the OS (Windows?) might take up +-2 GB, add RStudio, add antivirus, add some other software, add 2 copies of your data 710 MB*2 and you run out easily. So, maybe after each iteration, save the subset to disk, delete the object in R to free up memory and then go to the next one.

Comment: I was about to make the same point as jakub - if your total system memory is only 4GB, then 710MB is a large R object, and your first line is going to use *at least* another 710MB.

One pragmatic solution might be to do your data munging on an EC2 server, that you use for one hour. Another might be to use the Bloomberg API to request less data at a time?

Comment: execution on cloud is the costly solution but seems like effective one in this case.